# Node JS Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Having some trouble understanding callbacks, heres my code for authentication (via MySQL)

```
function authenticate(username, password, callback) {
    var query = "SELECT * from mydb.users where username='" + username + "'and BINARY password='" + password + "'";
    connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
        if (rows[0] != undefined) {
            if ('username' in rows[0]) {
                if (rows[0].username == username) {
                    callback(true);
                }
            }
        }
        callback(false);
    });
};

exports.assets=function(req,res) {
    var username = req.param("username");
    var password = req.param("password");

    authenticate(username, password, function (didAuthenticate) {
        if (didAuthenticate) {
            console.log("Authenticated");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Failed");
        }
    }); 
};
```

Output when user/pass matches:

```
Authenticated
Failed
```

With no match:

```
Failed
```

How come the if/else statement doesn't work when didAuthenticate returns true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply doing `callback(...)` does not end the execution of the function; you need a return statement to tell the function to stop running, as seen below:

```
function authenticate(username, password, callback) {
    var query = "SELECT * from mydb.users where username='" + username + "'and BINARY password='" + password + "'";
    connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
        if (rows[0] != undefined) {
            if ('username' in rows[0]) {
                if (rows[0].username == username) {
                    return callback(true);
                }
            }
        }
        return callback(false);
    });
};
```

You will see this technique used when you read other NodeJS code.

Comment: +1  This is a common but slightly confusing pattern when first seen.  Note that the `returns` are _not_ there to return a value (most likely nobody is listening), they are there as _flow control_ only.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a return statement to terminate you could put an else statement for your failure condition.

```
function authenticate(username, password, callback) {
    var query = "SELECT * from mydb.users where username='" + username + "'and BINARY     password='" + password + "'";
    connection.query(query, function (err, rows) {
        if (rows[0] != undefined && rows[0].username === username) {
            callback(true);
        }
        else {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
};
```